# Joomla Jform radio button not horizontally aligned with its label

Tags: css, radio-button, joomla3.0

I'm working on a custom Joomla module displaying a JForm with some radio buttons. I'm using the sample code described for Joomla 3+ styling with arbitrary values described here: https://docs.joomla.org/Radio_form_field_type

```
<field name="PrevVisits" type="radio" default="0" label="MOD_GNG_TOURPREF_PREV_VISITS" description="" class="btn-group">
                    <option value="Yes">MOD_GNG_TOURPREF_PREV_VISITS_YES</option>
                    <option value="Some">MOD_GNG_TOURPREF_PREV_VISITS_SOME</option>
                    <option value="No">MOD_GNG_TOURPREF_PREV_VISITS_NO</option>
</field>
```

I tried to remove the class tag, and this way the radio buttons are displayed, but the buttons and corresponding label are not horizontally aligned, but underneath each other:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYBCX.png)

In the below forum response, I got the following hints:

> Ok I see the issue. If you inspect the element for both the checkbox
>   and radio, you'll notice the checkbox input is inside the label, but
>   the radio input is before the label.
>
> Checkbox:

```
<label for="main_Interests7" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="main_Interests7" name="main[Interests][]" value="language"> Sprache
</label>
```

> Radio:

```
<input type="radio" id="main_PrevVisits0" name="main[PrevVisits]" value="Yes">
<label for="main_PrevVisits0">Ja</label>
```

> So due to label having it's display property set to block, it will
>   appear at 100% width on a separate line.
>
> The markup for these should be the same, so I believe it's a template
>   override that may have changed the markup.

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24531/jform-radio-button-not-displayed-or-not-horizontally-aligned-with-its-label/24534#24534

Here is link to the actual page:
https://www.dev.gonativeguide.com/de/tour-preferences?tid=12

My question is that based on the above assumption that my template overrides the normal radio-box behavior, how could I figure our what part of my template is responsible for this issue and what do I need to do to actually fix it?

Thanks, 
W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two simple CSS suggestions:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/axeKPG

```
/* Option 1 - horizontal */
#main_PrevVisits label{
  display:inline-block !important;
  margin-right:20px
} 


/* Option 2 - vertical */
#main_PrevVisits label{
  display:inline;
}

#main_PrevVisits label:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

The reason for your problem is that CSS on line 884 of https://www.dev.gonativeguide.com/templates/theme1990/css/bootstrap.css sets

```
label {
    display: block;
}
```

so the radio labels won't share the line with the radio buttons.

... and to answer your question about how to find out what part of your template is responsible, web inspector is your goto tool for troubleshooting like this. Inspect the element you are interested in, ie the radio label. [image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I tried your option #1, it worked, but it put all three radios and their 3 labels in one single line. What I really want is one radio and one label in one line, then new line and so on... Should option #2 solve this? I also tried option #2, but I did not see any change, but this might be CSS cache issue, I often don't see any change for some time...

Comment: #2 should get the result you are looking for @wanderlusted. If you'd like to make the change then let me know when it's done, I'll check it out. Maybe we'll need to tweak my suggestion.

Comment: I actually uploaded your #2 a few hours ago, but it does not really do the job. Any further hints are highly appreciated... Thanks @David Taiaora  !

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @wanderlusted. I checked the URL of your site that you posted but couldn't see where you had added #2.  Please see my update at the end of my suggestion above. I hope this helps!

Comment: It might have been a caching issue, now #2 works as expected. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Excellent, thanks for letting me know @wanderlusted. Good luck with the rest of your work!